# Captured image stretches wrongly after cropping in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera, crop

I want to *capture an image from my camera and crop the captured image at specified co-ordinates* then draw it on the middle of another image. The following code doesn't crash, but the captured image is screwing up, **since the image stretches wrong.**

Where am I going wrong?

Merry X'mas!

```
 //Get the bottom image Bitmap  

Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), SelectDollarActivity.selectedImageId);

//Get the  captured image Bitmap   

Bitmap capturedImage  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(CaptureImage.cImagePath) ; 

//************ CROP THE CAPTURED IMAGE *******************   


int targetBitmapWidth = bottomImage.getWidth();    
int targetBitmapHeight = bottomImage.getHeight() ;       

//create a Bitmap with specified width & height

Bitmap clippedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetBitmapWidth, targetBitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 

//Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into.

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(clippedBitmap);   

//**************  cropping process goes HERE......... 

//Create a new rectangle with the specified coordinates  

RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

//Create an empty path 

Path path = new Path();  

//Add a closed oval contour to the path  

path.addOval(rectf, Path.Direction.CW);   

//Intersect the current clip with the specified path  : CROPPING 

canvas.clipPath(path); 

canvas.drawBitmap(capturedImage, null, new Rect(0, 0, targetBitmapWidth, targetBitmapHeight), null);

   //******** MERGING PROCESS *******************           

//Construct a canvas with the specified bitmap to draw into.  

Canvas combo = new Canvas(bottomImage);   

// Then draw the second on top of that 

combo.drawBitmap(clippedBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);  

 // bottomImage is now a composite of the two. so, display the bottom image     


//************** DISPLAY THE MERGED IMAGE ****************   

((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.billImage)).setImageBitmap(bottomImage);
```

Comment: image is stretching. that is my problem.

Comment: I'am cropping my captured image in an elliptical fashion and placing in the middle of another/bottom image. I'am able to place the cropped image at the proper position on bottom image.  But i'am getting stretched elliptical image.   Where i'am wrong ?

Comment: did you get any solution bro? im also facing this same issue.pls reply me back

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) states that drawBitmap accepts two more arguments, width and heights. In your code,

```
combo.drawBitmap(clippedBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
```

only has the positioning.

You will need to set a few more arguments of course, but it should work :D